# Problema al renderizar un elemento con razor en visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, razor

tengo un problema para renderizar un elemento.

```
@{
    if (Session["mensaje"] != null)
    {
        <div class="text-center" id="mensajePerAviso">

            <p>Atención!.<br />@Session["mensaje"]</p>
            <button onclick="cerrarMensaje()" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

El flujo es, que a través de una petición ajax pasa por un método del controlador que marca la variable de sesión "mensaje" y lo redirige al index, pero no carga el div mensajeperaviso. Tengo otro método igual en estructura que lo redirige al index también, pero con éste el elemento se muestra.

```
 [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddMember(string idm)
        {
            Collection<ErrorRecord> errores = PowerShellHelper.AddOrgContactFromGroup(lastOpenedG.Id, idm);
            if (errores.Count() > 0)
            {
                contr = vueltas + 1;
                Session["mensaje"] = "El Usuario ya pertenece a éste grupo, operación cancelada";
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

En el index, despúes de hacer varias operaciones, devuelvo la vista con un modelo.

```
return View(model);
```

He comprobado que asigne la variable de sesion y el flujo vaya por donde yo quiero, pero no entiendo porqué en un caso lo renderiza y en otro no.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda para entender porqué ésto pasa.
Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Puedes mostrar como realizas la llamada ajax? Ya que al realizar una llamada ajax no estas renderizando de nuevo porque el resultado lo tienes en la llamada ajax y tienes que ser tú quien indique los cambios que se tienen que hacer.

Answer (score 0):

La llamada ajax no es la que renderizaba de nuevo la vista en el método funcional, 
si no una función en el succes, siento las molestias.